# python flask import error when I install the IDE and Run by Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, web, flask, cmd

[When I Run by Esclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M78Kp.jpg)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is error msg.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "C:\Users\Austyn\git\flask\ch02\hello.py", line 3, in <module>
>
>     from flask import Flask
>
>   File "C:\Python36\myprojects\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py",
>   line 19, in <module>
>
>     from jinja2 import Markup, escape
>
>   File "C:\Python36\myprojects\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py",
>   line 33, in <module>
>
>     from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
>
>  File"C:\Python36\myprojects\venv\lib\sitepackages\jinja2\environment.py",
>  line 15, in <module>
>
>     from jinja2 import nodes
>
>   File "C:\Python36\myprojects\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\nodes.py"line
>   19, in <module>
>
>     from jinja2.utils import Markup
>
>   File "C:\Python36\myprojects\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py"line
>   624, in <module>
>
>     from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
>
>   File"C:\Python36\myprojects\venv\lib\sipackages\markupsafe\__init__.py",
>   line 14, in <module>
>
>     from markupsafe._compat import text_type, string_types, int_types, \
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe._compat'
> ```

When I have tried installing flask I'm in a trouble.
I have no idea why occur that error.
Am I wrong set up the PATH?
I think it doesn't work sideTools like werkzeug and jinja2 and Markupsafe...
But I have no idea what is this.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install markupsafe.

```
pip install markupsafe
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this commands to fix the problem:

```
pip uninstall markupsafe
pip install MarkupSafe==2.1.1
```

Hope it helps :)